# HTML form if one radio condition is selected then force an input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML form with two inputs. One is a radio input and the other is a numeric input. 
Using a Javascript function, if the radio option is selected as Insurance - YES(1), then the script must force a numeric value input on the Insurance Value ins_value input. If the radio input is selected as NO, then no input to be entered in the text input.

I have tried to find a similar example but have only found simple examples where an alert is triggered. 
I am learning Javascript and have been through tutorials - but also no similar examples.

```
<script>
    function INSURANCE() {
        var insurance = document.forms["RegForm"]["optradio"];
        var ins_value = document.forms["RegForm"]["ins_value"];

        if (insurance.value == 0) {
            "";
            return false;
        } else  {
        if (ins_value.value == "") {
            window.alert("Please insert Insurance value.");
            ins_value.focus();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

I expect once the form is submitted, it should either force an insurance value input or not, based on the radio input selection.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a checkbox for you're use case. Radio buttons force a selection of one in many. You only have a "is numeric" flag meaning you're value is either true or false.

Well I guess you can achieve you're goal by changing you're input type according to user selection:

```
<input id="optcheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="HandleCheckboxClick();" />
<input id="ins_value" type="text" onclick="HandleCheckboxClick();" />

<script>
  function HandleCheckboxClick() {
    var type = 'text';
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('optcheckbox');
    if(checkbox.checked) {
      type = 'number';
    }
    document.getElementById('ins_value').type = type;
  }
</script>
```

I hope that helps.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Only seeing the Javascript it's difficult to figure out what's going on, including the HTML would help a lot. Also, this question is a big vague which is makes it hard to answer.

First, when are you trying to trigger the forcing the numeric value? When the user clicks on the radio button? If so, then call that function on the change event. If you're going to change it on the submit, then put the code in the submit function.

I recommend building an array of numeric values and matching that up with the 0, 1, 2, ... values of the radio buttons. When you set the text input, plug that value into your numeric array.

Here's a JS fiddle of using an array in conjunction with the radio button values.

https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Hayes/coxta1bw/1/

```
var form = document.querySelector("form");

var numbers = [30, 20, 80];

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  form["textinput"].value = numbers[form["contact"].value]
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

If the user skips the radio buttons, just make that check in the on submit function before filling in the numerical input.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var radio = document.getElementById('optradio');
                var input = document.getElementById('ins_value');
                radio.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    if(radio.value == 0){
                        radio.value = 1;
                        this.checked = true;
                        input.removeAttribute('disabled')
                        input.value = radio.value;
                    }
                    else{
                        radio.value = 0;
                        input.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
                        input.value = '';
                        this.checked = false;
                    }
                });
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="optradio" value="0">
            <input type="number" name="ins_value" id="ins_value" value="" disabled>
```

add `disabled` attribute to your numeric input like so

html:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="optradio" value="0">
<input type="number" name="ins_value" id="ins_value" value="" disabled>
```

javacript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var radio = document.getElementById('optradio');
            var input = document.getElementById('ins_value');
            radio.addEventListener("click", function(){
                if(radio.value == 0){
                    radio.value = 1;
                    this.checked = true;
                    input.removeAttribute('disabled')
                    input.value = radio.value;
                }
                else{
                    radio.value = 0;
                    input.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
                    input.value = '';
                    this.checked = false;
                }
            });
        </script>
```

add the script below your html code